# in a single query without cte , derived table or any temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i wrote this query using cte   , but i need to have this query with out cte . as a single query

```sql
DECLARE @eventdate AS datetime;
SELECT @eventdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

WITH cte AS(
    SELECT organizationname,
           claimstate,
           DATEDIFF(dd, claimcreationtimestamp, @eventdate)
           - CASE WHEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, claimcreationtimestamp, @eventdate), claimcreationtimestamp) > @eventdate THEN
                      1
                 ELSE 0
             END AS Age,
           COUNT(claimnumber) AS count
    FROM caseclaims cc
        INNER JOIN organizations o ON cc.organizationid = o.organizationid
    GROUP BY claimstate,
             organizationname,
             claimcreationtimestamp
)
SELECT organizationname,
       claimstate,
       CASE WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 19 AND 31 THEN 'Age 20-30'
           WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 29 AND 41 THEN 'Age 30-40'
           WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 39 AND 51 THEN 'Age 40-50'
           WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 49 AND 61 THEN 'Age 50-60'
           WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 59 AND 81 THEN 'Age 60-80'
           WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 79 AND 101 THEN 'Age 80-100'
           ELSE 'Age >100'
       END AS [Age],
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM cte
GROUP BY CASE WH EN cte.Age BETWEEN 19 AND 31 THEN 'Age 20-30'
             WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 29 AND 41 THEN 'Age 30-40'
             WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 39 AND 51 THEN 'Age 40-50'
             WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 49 AND 61 THEN 'Age 50-60'
             WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 59 AND 81 THEN 'Age 60-80'
             WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 79 AND 101 THEN 'Age 80-100'
             ELSE 'Age >100'
         END,
         claimstate,
         organizationname;
```

Comment: You can't write the query in a concise way without using a CTE. That's what CTEs are good for. It's certainly possible to do so, but it will become a very long query.

Comment: Aside: What is the purpose of the overlapping ranges, e.g. 19 to 31 and 29 to 41? The result is well defined by `case`, but it doesn't appear to make life any easier for someone trying to understand or maintain the code.

Comment: you could replace the cte with a view, or embed it as a sub-query. but why?

Comment: Please explain the issue with CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `CROSS APPLY` to create new virtual columns within the query, obviating the need for a CTE.**

```sql
DECLARE @eventdate AS datetime;
SELECT @eventdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

SELECT
       organizationname,
       claimstate,
       Age,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM caseclaims cc
INNER JOIN organizations o ON cc.organizationid = o.organizationid

CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
       DATEDIFF(dd, claimcreationtimestamp, @eventdate)
       - CASE WHEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, claimcreationtimestamp, @eventdate), claimcreationtimestamp) > @eventdate THEN
                  1
             ELSE 0
         END
) ) AS v1(Age)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
       CASE WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 19 AND 31 THEN 'Age 20-30'
           WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 29 AND 41 THEN 'Age 30-40'
           WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 39 AND 51 THEN 'Age 40-50'
           WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 49 AND 61 THEN 'Age 50-60'
           WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 59 AND 81 THEN 'Age 60-80'
           WHEN cte.Age BETWEEN 79 AND 101 THEN 'Age 80-100'
           ELSE 'Age >100'
       END
) ) AS v2([Age])

GROUP BY v2.Age,
         claimstate,
         organizationname;
```

I note that your existing query did not seem to be counting correctly, so multiple `claimcreationtimestamp` values were only counted once.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that you will have a great benefit using a tally table containing the intervals you have to define for your age histograms.

Then make a join with the BETWEEN operator